# Ambiguity in the sentence "In case of fire, do not use elevator."

Tags: ambiguity

The aforementioned sentence arises in an assignment of the course *Introduction to Mathematical Thinking*, where the notion of literary ambiguity is made explicit in our everyday use of language. However, unlike with the sentence *"No head injury is too trivial to ignore"*(which, to my surprise, has already been asked about on English.SE), I cannot figure out any ambiguity with the current phrasing of the sentence. The answer seeks two ambiguous interpretations which deviate from the originally intended meaning, and I would like this dilemma to be resolved.

(Further tags may be added as deemed suitable, I can only call this a simple case of ambiguity for now)

Comment: I too fail to see any ambiguity in that sentence. The only meaning I can construe is "If there's a fire, don't use the elevator."

Comment: The *supposed* "ambiguity" is *Don't use the elevator **in case doing so causes a fire***, but that's such a perverse interpretation and so non-idiomatically phrased I don't really see the point in bringing it up.

Comment: @Robusto I guess literary ambiguity is hard to spot. Since this is from a mathematical viewpoint, it might be the case that *not specifying where the fire is* and *which elevator to use(there's no article preceding the word elevator)* is the only source of ambiguity.

Comment: There are plenty of ambiguous sentences ("I saw someone on the hill with a telescope") but these are not among them – neither could really be misunderstood.

Comment: True, I'm starting to get a feeling that this sentence may not be ambiguous at all from a literary perspective, but only from a mathematical one(since mathematical statements need precision, not specifying *which* fire and *which* elevator can lead to humorous conclusions).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I still can't wrap my mind around that. To me it would require some mention of causality to get to that interpretation, and even if you have that any ambiguity will in any case have been eliminated. Perhaps I'm too used to seeing that warning in, oh, *every* public building I've ever been in that has an elevator.

Comment: Mathematically the statement seems to boil down to `if fire no elevator` which is not ambiguous either.

Comment: @Robusto True, but the deviation from given statement is exaggerated. The point is not to create a perfect mathematical statement *but to alter the given statement which seems unambiguous to a mathematician*, without losing its meaning in real life.

Comment: A possible reformulation could be "In case of fire in the building, do not use this elevator". The only thing IMO which needs a rigorous mathematical meaning now is the idea of "fire in the building".

Comment: @Robusto: I agree the "using the elevator might ***cause*** a fire" reading is a bit of a stretch. But compare *Don't shout in case you wake the baby* *(in case = **lest**)* and *Here's money for a taxi in case you need it* *(in case = **if**)*. Not sure exactly why *those* examples work without having to mess about with a preposition and relativizer to give us ***in the case that** = in a situation where = when* for the ***if*** sense.

Comment: “This elevator” suggests it might be okay to use the other elevator, which would be wrong. Most sentences  are ambiguous if you stretch assumptions enough, but at least on signs you want messages quickly read, perhaps by NNSs, and quickly understood as you want them to be.

Comment: Cross-dupe on ELL.SE: [Possible meanings of “IN CASE OF FIRE, DO NOT USE ELEVATOR.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/281261/11157)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has brought up that in case of fire you don't use elevator.. use water.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider "in case of accidents, don't drive too fast". In that case it's clear that not driving too fast is to avoid accidents (though clearly driving fast near them isn't a great idea either).

The alternative meaning in your example is "to avoid fires, don't use the elevator". That's nonsensical, so there's no everyday ambiguity and we all understand  "if there's a fire, don't use the elevator"

Comment: That's one possibility, but the question seeks two such ambiguous interpretations.

Comment: It's only a *hypothetical* "alternative meaning". In practice OP's phrasing would ***never*** be used by a native speaker to convey the sense given here. So asking for ***two*** "alternative meanings" just seems utterly pointless, since even the most obvious "alternative" would never actually "exist" in the real world.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aah...the real world aspect. Perhaps that's the point of the question itself, and the very reason why the question isn't best suited to English.SE :) Maybe I'll ask on Math.SE

Comment: I think that's also pointless. Whether you aski here or on Math.SE, the problem is you're trying to treat natural language on a par with computer code. The former is often *deliberately* shaped in favour of ambiguity (which is an essential characteristic of all natural languages), but obviously one of the fundamental requirements of a computer language is that the "meaning" should be 100% fixed - fully defined and unambiguous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Consider the phrasing: "Do not use this elevator in case a fire breaks out in this building"- the point I'm making about is *specification* of the entity corresponding to that particular case. In the real world, a human would unambiguously deduce the meaning from context, but an abstraction *requires* the domain of discourse be specified.

Comment: In the real world, a *sensible* person would probably consider using non-ambiguous words (***if*** or ***lest***, for example) rather than ***in case***. Obviously a programmer in the equivalent "coding" context would always either choose or be forced to write unambiguous constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I acknowledge your point of view and end this discussion by saying that the nature of problem was a mathematical one, as opposed to(and initially believed by me) to be a linguistic one. All the points made by everyone are perfectly reasonable, and I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Sure. I'll just throw in my final tuppence worth then. Idiomatically as well as pragmatically, your example three comments ago can only be interpreted as having the ***lest*** sense. The ***if*** sense would normally require the "specification of the relevant entity" to include at least a preposition and relativizer - ***in the case that** = in a situation where = when*.

Comment: @Manan I assumed the primary meaning to be to obvious to be worth stating. I'll add it

Comment: "In case of accidents" does not mean the same as "in case you might cause an accident" but rather "In the case of one or more accident occurring". If there is an 'of' after 'case' it's referring to when the event is happening, so there is not ambiguity.